# Autoscaling Kubernetes based on number of Jobs on AWS EKS

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, amazon-eks, kubernetes-jobs

My cluster sometimes gets a "burst" of information and generates a large number of Kubernetes Jobs at once. And in other times I have ~0 active jobs.

I'm wondering how can I make it autoscale the number of nodes to continuously be able to process all these jobs in a reasonable time-frame.

I specifically use AWS EKS and each job takes a few minutes to complete.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

EKS allows you to deploy [cluster autoscaler](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/cluster-autoscaler.html) so when new job can not be scheduled due to lack of available cpu/memory, extra node will be added to the cluster.